# authentication with the username in mac

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

I tried to change my user name from apple to M Kumaran, after change of the username, username is not working for the authentication in the system preference to unlock make changes, for running in simulator authentication, etc. I think it occur due to the space in the username

In the finder home icon is shows as apple

in the terminal it shows as M-Kumaran:~ apple$

In the devices section it shows as M Kumaran

in the login screen of the system shows as apple

I tried all possibilities for the user name like

mkumaran

MKumaran

M Kumaran

M kumaran

M-Kumaran

apple

Apple

But it is not working

Can any one please help me with this authentication

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify exactly *what* you changed? Your account has two names: an "account name" (aka "short name", which should not contain spaces), and a "full name" (aka "long name", which *can* contain spaces). Your prompt suggests that the account name is "apple", and that it's the *computer name" that's been changed to "M Kumaran". So: please clarify exactly what you changed and where. Also, what does the `id -P` command print?

Comment: thanks for the reply, id -P returns this

apple:********:501:20::0:0:Apple:/Users/apple:/bin/bash

Comment: i tired the user name apple and password of that but it is not working, how to solve this

Comment: Thanks, i solve the problem by creating admin account by restarting the system and press command + S 

after that i gave the following command to create admin

1) mount -uw/

2) rm \var\db\.AppleSetupDone

3) reboot

then give the details to create the admin, once login into the admin account change the existing user account(apple) to correct with proper username, and then login into my account now everything is working for authentication

Comment: From the output of `id -P`, you'd never actually changed the username (either account name or full name). Was it actually the password you changed?

Comment: Thanks, i didn't changed the password, i fixed the problem by login into admin account and change the name correctly, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421067/5151882

Answer (score 1):

Don't use account names containing spaces.

From the [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548)

> When modifying the account name (short name) or home folder name, it **should not contain any spaces**. If the current account name already contains a space, you won't be able to edit this field until the space has been removed. Click immediately after the space, or use the left arrow key to move the text insertion point immediately after the space, then press the Delete key to remove the space.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i already changed, as i mention in devices (M Kumaran) and terminal ( M-Kumaran:~ apple$), remaining places it shows as apple, i don t know what mistake i done, but i cannot able the authenticate the username for change in the system preference and also in simulator, please help me how to view the exact user name to give for the authentication, or change the username

Comment: The mistake is the space character. UNIX doesn't like spaces. Do you have a second admin account? If yes use it to revert the short user name of the first admin account. You can change the short user name also in Terminal.app. But this is not trivial.

Comment: i don t have second account how to user  change it in terminal for authentication

Comment: i don t have second account how to  change username it in terminal for authentication

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, i solve the problem by creating admin account by restarting the system and press command + S

after that i gave the following command to create admin

1) mount -uw/

2) rm \var\db\ .AppleSetupDone (remove the space before .AppleSetupDone)

3) reboot

then give the details to create the admin, once login into the admin account change the existing user account(apple) to correct with proper username, and then login into my account now everything is working for authentication